# Javascript create 2 instances from 1 object

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I got two DIV container each of it contains a puzzle (realization with jquery draggables).

I also got one object which looks like:

```
var puzzle var puzzle = {
    option1 = [],
    init:function(container) { .... }
}
```

To start the puzzle for one DIV i use:

```
// left puzzle div
var puzzleLeft = puzzle;
puzzleLeft.init(leftContainer);

// right puzzle div
var puzzleRight = puzzle;
puzzleRight.init(leftContainer);
```

But for the left one its not working. Everything I'm going to do left, happens in the right one :/ When I uncomment the start code for the right one, it will work for the left :)
Seems to be the right one start code is wrong?
Is this a wrong way to create 2 instances of the puzzle?

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create class' constructor instead of object:

```
function Puzzle(){
   var self = this;

   self.option1 = [];
   self.init = function(container) { .... };
}
```

And create two instances of it:

```
// left puzzle div
var puzzleLeft = new Puzzle();
puzzleLeft.init(leftContainer);

// right puzzle div
var puzzleRight = new Puzzle();
puzzleRight.init(rightContainer);
```

Comment: It should work if management function is in the same namespace.

Answer (score 2):

### Prototypal Inheritance

Your title says **"create 2 instances from 1 object"**. That has prototypal inheritance written all over it.

You can use `Object.create` to create an object which inherits from another object.

```
// left puzzle div
var puzzleLeft = Object.create(puzzle);
puzzleLeft.init(leftContainer);

// right puzzle div
var puzzleRight = Object.create(puzzle);
puzzleRight.init(leftContainer);
```

However, any properties which reference an object will need to be set up inside your `init` function.  Something like this:

```
var puzzle = {

    // Let it be null for now
    option1: null,

    init: function(container) {
        // Set it to empty array inside init
        this.option1 = [ ];
    }

};
```

This will ensure that `puzzleLeft` and `puzzleRight` are working with different arrays.

---

### Cloning

If you're using a library like jQuery, another option is to simply clone the object.

```
// left puzzle div
var puzzleLeft = $.extend({ }, puzzle);
puzzleLeft.init(leftContainer);

// right puzzle div
var puzzleRight = $extend({ }, puzzle);
puzzleRight.init(leftContainer);
```

Using `$.extend({ }, someObject)` will make a copy of `someObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `puzzleLeft` and `puzzleRight` are the same objects as `puzzle`.

You can create Puzzle as

```
function puzzle(){
...
}
```

and use

```
new Puzzle()
```

or use clone function of jquery to create a copy of the object with a different reference

Comment: Do you have an example for the JQUERY clone of a object? I only found it for elements. Thx